# SQL query does not match like OR

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT `CARD_ID`, `CARD_NAME`, `CARD_SET`,`CARD_COLOR` 
FROM (`All_Cards_Ext`)
WHERE (`CARD_NAME` LIKE '%hearts%' AND `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%R%)
GROUP BY `CARD_NAME`LIMIT 9;
```

This one works correctly returns to me

```
--------------------------------------
51| Ace of Hearts | Bridge | R 
52| Jack of Hearts| Bridge | R
```

However the query below does not:

```
SELECT `CARD_ID`, `CARD_NAME`, `CARD_SET`,`CARD_COLOR`
FROM (`All_Cards_Ext`) 
WHERE (`CARD_NAME` LIKE 'hearts%' AND `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%R%' OR `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%B%' )GROUP BY `CARD_NAME`LIMIT 9;
```

This one does not work it returns random records it seems the criteria after the OR does work correctly:

> `-------------------------------------- 
>   34| Ace of Diamonds | Bridge | D
>
>   35| Two of Diamonds | Bridge | D`

..

Comment: You may want to try adding extra brackets to make sure you are getting the 'and' and 'or' in the correct order.

Comment: Is this right way of using `'hearts%'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE (`CARD_NAME` LIKE 'hearts%' AND `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%R%' OR `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%B%' )GROUP BY `CARD_NAME`LIMIT 9;
```

Should be

```
WHERE (`CARD_NAME` LIKE 'hearts%' AND (`CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%R%' OR `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%B%' )GROUP BY `CARD_NAME`LIMIT 9;
```

For a simple example [See Example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You need to group your OR conditions like `some and (someother or someother or someother )`

```
SELECT `CARD_ID`, `CARD_NAME`, `CARD_SET`,`CARD_COLOR`
FROM (`All_Cards_Ext`) 
WHERE `CARD_NAME` LIKE 'hearts%' AND 
(`CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%R%' OR `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%B%' )
GROUP BY `CARD_NAME`LIMIT 9;
```

Answer (score 2):

Watch where you're applying your parentheses':

```
...
WHERE (`CARD_NAME` LIKE 'hearts%' AND (`CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%R%' OR `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%B%'))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use this and get rid of OR ...

```
  AND `CARD_COLOR` in ( 'R' ,'B' )
```

instead of

```
  AND `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%R%' OR `CARD_COLOR` LIKE '%B%'
```

like that :

```
 WHERE `CARD_NAME` LIKE 'hearts%' AND `CARD_COLOR` in ( 'R' ,'B' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing brackets on the color comparison 
(CARD_NAME LIKE 'hearts%' AND (CARD_COLOR LIKE '%R%' OR CARD_COLOR LIKE '%B%') )